# How to re-order a while loop by the sum of two of its values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with names and numbers in which I make a SELECT and then a WHILE loop to display results, but the value I need to order the whole table, comes from the sum of three numeric fields on each row , and this is also a new value to display. I considered to convert this sum into an array and sort it, but how this sort can affect and reorder other data?

Comment: you can sort it when you query from db - order by

Answer (score 0):

Do the arithmetic in the SELECT query then order it by that column.

```
SELECT field1+field2+field3 AS Sumof123 FROM Table1 ORDER BY Sumof123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MySql SUM()

```sql
SELECT (SUM(column1)+SUM(column2)+SUM(column3)) AS totalvalue FROM your_table ORDER BY 1 ASC
```